# PHP - How to share JSON data between files

Tags: php

So I'm trying to make a simple API, I have tried lots of different things. I want to show a random number on my JSON object and a token to go with it, then store both in a database. I don't want this to happen when you visit the webpage I want the data to get sent to a DB and generated from a separate page.

The first step in this is getting data from a different file.

Here's what I tried first:

index.php:

```
    <?php

$odds = rand(1, 100);

?>

<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
{
    "odds": <?php echo $odds;?> 
}
</pre>
```

Here's the file I'm trying to get the data from:

```
    <?php

$url = "https://flugscoding.com/random/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Riverside API");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

if(!$response = curl_exec($ch)) {
echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($response, true);
echo $data->odds;
?>
```

Error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'odds' of non-object in D:\xxamp\htdocs\random\perp.php on line 16
```

What I tried after:

index.php:

```
     <?php

$values = array("odds"=>rand(1, 100));
echo json_encode($values);

?>
```

Here's the file I'm trying to get the data from:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("index.php");        
echo $json;     
// echo $json->odds;

?>
```

Error:

```
It doesn't show any data or errors, just a blank screen.
```

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem? I'm trying to make a provably fair system for a friend.

Comment: Read the docs for the second parameter of json_decode: "When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays."

Comment: I changed it to this `$json = file_get_contents("index.php");        
$data = json_decode($json);     
echo $data[0];
` and I still get a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You're really close in both your examples:

**#1**

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
echo $data->odds;
```

You're passing `true` into `json_decode` which makes it an associative array, not an object. So you will need to get the odds with `$data['odds'];` instead.

**#2**

```
$json = file_get_contents("index.php");        
echo $json;
```

`file_get_contents` can either fetch a local file or remote file. In this case, you're passing a local file, so `$json` is the contents of the PHP code.

You can either:

(a) redesign it so that `index.php` is a function, and you can call the function from different files
(b) call `index.php` remotely and parse the results

a. Create a function in `index.php` that can get the odds:

```
<?php

    function getData() [
        return array("odds"=>rand(1, 100));
    }
```

Then, in another file, you can:

```
<?php

    require_once 'index.php';

    $data = getData(); //now you have access to $data['odds'];
```

b. Call `index.php` remotely, like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://localhost/index.php");        
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```